# JavaScript Encode

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, decode, encode, extjs

Surfing on web i find Ext.Gantt plugin for ExtJS, that extension have a special encode. Anybody know how to encode like that or another complicated form.

[Encoded Gantt Chart](http://www.ext-scheduler.com/js/sch-gantt-all-debug.js)

Comment: Are you looking for a description of how to do a Gantt chart in JS? What does the encode have to do with it?

Comment: @Jared: Look at the link, the Gantt chart plugin in question is obfuscated.

Comment: @mu - You're right, didn't even see it. Should we de-obfuscate it?

Comment: http://www.bryntum.com/gantt/

Comment: @Jared: I think he's asking if anyone knows what obfuscator was used or if anyone knows of a similar one.

Comment: @mu - Well, I'm fresh out of ideas.

Comment: encoding JavaScript for reasons of intellectual copyright protection is inefficient and useless. In fact, many (if not all) encoders require the use of the JavaScript 'eval'-command to decode everything back. Anybody with enough knowledge of JavaScript to do anything with your script is able to replace 'encode' with 'document.write' or 'console.log' and he has the complete un-encoded script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be obfuscated by Dean Edwards's Packer, and then further converted into hex notation.

Just copy everything from `var _0x5749 =` to just before `eval(function`.  Open up FireBug, paste it into console, and print out the variable.  It is a JavaScript program that has been obfuscated by Dean Edwards' Packer.

Packer-encoded scripts have a signature: `eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){` which in this case is converted to `eval(function (_0x68cdx1, _0x68cdx2, _0x68cdx3, _0x68cdx4, _0x68cdx5, _0x68cdx6) { _0x68cdx5 = function (_0x68cdx3) {`.  Notice that "e" is encoded to _0x68cdx5, and "c" is encoded to _0x68cdx3.

There are web tools to decode Dean Edwards' Packer, but there is a very simple way to get the script text:

1. Copy all the code up to (but not including) `Ext.onReady(function() {`
2. Look for `eval(function(...`
3. Replace "eval" with "console.log"
4. Run the script in node.js, or JsShell, or Rhino, or FireBug, or the Developer Console of Chrome or Safari
5. The script in plain text is printed the the console
6. Copy the script and pass it through an on-line JavaScript beautifier
7. I got 3,839 lines after using: http://jsbeautifier.org/

I would only call this **simplistic** obfuscation as the raw source code can be obtained through a decoding process.

The best obfuscator I recommend is the Google Closure Compiler in **ADVANCED** mode -- which makes scripts almost impossible to reverse-engineer.

Comment: @richardhell, the Closure Compiler is really one of the best.  However, beware that its restrictions are very high for using the Advanced mode -- but the results are generally well worth it, especially when you care about protecting your intellectual property.

Comment: Thanks for sharing details on how to read my source :). Guess I'll need to switch to using closure compiler for my next release.

Comment: @mats, not at all!  ;-D  If you're into obfuscation (which I believe you are since your modules are commercial products), then you can't go wrong with the Closure Compiler.  However, beware that you'll need the **Advanced** mode, not the Simple mode.  You'll also need to scrub your code very carefully since there are severe restrictions in using the Advanced mode.  You'll also need to make an "externs" file for Ext.Js for the functions of Ext that you use.